# What should I do if I cannot understand a peer reviewer's comment?

Tags: peer-review, computer-science

I have submitted a paper to a journal in the field of computer science. My paper was accepted with major revisions. However, a reviewer asked : " Give more  **mathematical treatment** of the proposed algorithm; What are its pros ? ; Author must explain "  .
I do not understand what they mean with mathematical treatment. Should I analyze my proposed system mathematically ? Can you please help me understand the reviewer’s comment?

Comment: What does your advisor think it means?

Comment: The title and body of your question don't match, the former is a generalized question (what should I do when I don't understand a reviewers comment?) that could (once successfully answered) yield interesting insight for other with the same problem. The latter is very personal (How should I interpret a specific remark that I do not understand) and is difficult to answer here. I am thus voting to close.

Comment: possible duplicate / general advice: https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/177505/understanding-reviewers-comments-on-research-paper

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We cannot say exactly what is needed in your case without seeing the algorithm and the context. It might mean that you should prove its asymptotic speed or memory use using [big O notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation), and compare to a different algorithm.

Answer (score 9):

I would mention it *now* to the editor and ask if the reviewer can give a bit more guidance. I'd do this concurrently with starting on the major corrections, just to save time. If you wait for another submission to bring it up then it will delay things (at best). It seems like a mistake to put it off and any answer can guide your revisions.

It is likely, however, that the reviewer is asking about theoretical efficiency of the algorithm or some proof of correctness in a few cases. You might even phrase your inquiry with one of these suggestions or anything else you can think of.

Answer (score 3):

The reviewer should have been more clear. Rather than guess, you should contact the editor right away, and request a clarification.

However if I had proposed a new algorithm and received this suggestion, then I would  try to compare, for the new algorithm and for commonly used algorithms, statistics such as the worst-case run time, expected run time, memory requrements, how well it parallelizes.

An example of a simple undergraduate book showing how this can be done: Thomas H.Cormen, Charles E. Leiserson, Ronald L. Rivest, Clifford  Stein. Introduction to Algorithms. Chapter II "Sorting and Order Statistics". It shows that for Quicksort,  the worst-case running time is Θ(n²), while the average-case/expected
running time is Θ(n log n). For some new sort algorithm, making up the staistics, the proponent might say than the average time is only Θ(n), a pro, while the worse case time is Θ(n³), a con, compared to Quicksort.

I don't know whether your paper already has this analysis & comparisons. Perhaps the reviewer meant something else, such as a mathematical proof that your algorithm actually works. You need to ask the editor.

Answer (score -4):

If the paper is accepted with major corrections, I would do the possible corrections and let the referee knows that we could not understand the requirements in the given point by the referees.

Comment: Think you mmarmelomartelo. Should i mention to this in my response or just sending a letter to editor telling them that we didn't understand the following comment

Comment: Why would you wait and then submit a revision known to be inadequate along with the issue?

Comment: Sorry, my suggestion is to say in your reply to the referee that you didn't fully understand the question and NOT the editor. A direct approach to the editor would be offensive in my opinion